# setting location.href = '/foo' works on live, not on IIS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

In javascript I'm doing this:

```
location.href = '/foo'
```

and this works when I deploy on the live server, or in Visual Studio using the `http` launch profile (which also launches a console app, that shows all the sql queries),

however if I select IIS (in VS launch profile), and my initial url is `http://localhost/myapp`
than setting `location.href` will change the url to `http://localhost/foo` instead of `http://localhost/myapp/foo`

Comment: since all of that just happens inside the browser via javascript it seems unlikely that the server should make any difference. otoh computers are the devil's work so what do i know. in any case, the leading `/` *should* go to `localhost/foo`. If you want to append a segment to the current url, drop the `/`.

Comment: well, I could be located at `localhost/myapp/page2` and I want to go to `localhost/myapp/foo`,  so appending is not what I need

Comment: so change it to `location.href = '/myapp/foo'` or even `location.href = 'http://localhost/myapp/foo'`?

Comment: if I put `/myapp/foo`, on production it would try to go to `example.com/myapp/foo` instead of `example.com/foo`

Comment: are you using something like `app.UsePathBase("/myapp")`?

Comment: no, this is code in a js file

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing something like this:
[image]

When you use `location.href = '/foo'`, tt actually redirects to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo` directory, not the foo folder in your project root. You should get a 404 error.

you should modify you code to:

```
location.href = "foo";
```

and you will get a 403 error code, then add a default page(eg, index.html) will be ok.
like this:
[image]

Comment: location.href = "foo" redirects to `localhost/foo` while  I need it to go to `localhost/myapp/foo`

Comment: I've tested the above, so I'm not sure if I reproduce your issue. If possible, please provide specific steps to reproduce the issue.